# What is the correct way to store client variables in SignalR?

Tags: signalr

Currently, I am using a `Dictionary` and `Context.User.Identity.Name` (code condensed for brevity):

```
[Authorize]
public class ServiceHub : Hub
{
    static private Dictionary<string, HubUserProcess> UserProcesses = new Dictionary<string, HubUserProcess>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        UserProcesses[Context.User.Identity.Name] = new HubUserProcess();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        // ... Remove from dictionary if key exists (not shown) ...
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    // Then I use UserProcesses[Context.User.Identity.Name] in all functions
}
```

In my `HubUserProcess` class, I have a bunch of web services that initialize in the constructor using the `Context.User.Identity.Name`. A coworker said that my approach is unsafe, so my biggest worry is one user accessing another user's private data (these variables can hold very sensitive information). What is the correct/safe way to store client variables?

Comment: IMHO, I don't see anything wrong with it. It's not easy to fake the Identity and if someone can do that, the bet is off on pretty much everything. You might wanna use a dictionary that supports multiple threads, `ConcurrentDictionary` I think and make sure you always use the context identity

Comment: Just a said note, this way all connections for the same user will share the UserProcesses instance. So if the same user has two windows open he will use the same UserProcesses for both connections